# How do Scrapy from_settings and from_crawler class methods work?

Tags: scrapy, class-method

I need to add the following class method to my existing pipeline
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-m-getting-an-error-cannot-import-name-crawler

i am not sure how to have 2 of these class methods in my class

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import MySQLdb.cursors

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
    """A pipeline to store the item in a MySQL database.
    This implementation uses Twisted's asynchronous database API.
    """
    def __init__(self, dbpool):
        self.dbpool = dbpool

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        dbargs = dict(
            host= settings['DB_HOST'],
            db= settings['DB_NAME'],
            user= settings['DB_USER'],
            passwd= settings['DB_PASSWD'],
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True,
        )
        dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', **dbargs)
        return cls(dbpool)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding of [class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner), several class methods in a python class should just be [fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972379/688161). It just depends on which one the caller requires. However, I have only seen `from_crawler` until now [in scrapy pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075941/how-to-access-scrapy-settings-from-item-pipeline). From there you can get access to the settings via `crawler.settings`

Are you sure that `from_settings` is required? I did not check all occurences, but in `middleware.py` priority seems to apply: If a `crawler` object is available and a `from_crawler` method exists, this is taken. Otherwise, if there is a `from_settings` method, that is taken. Otherwise, the raw constructor is taken.

```
if crawler and hasattr(mwcls, 'from_crawler'):                  
    mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)                            
elif hasattr(mwcls, 'from_settings'):                           
    mw = mwcls.from_settings(settings)                          
else:                                                           
    mw = mwcls()
```

I admit, I do not know if this is also the place where pipelines get created (I guess not, but there is no pipelines.py), but the implementation seems very reasonable.

So, I'd just either:

- reimplement the whole method as `from_crawler` and only use that one
- add method `from_crawler` and use both

The new method could look like follows (to duplicate as little code as possible):

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    obj = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
    obj.do_something_on_me_with_crawler(crawler)
    return obj
```

Of course this depends a bit on what you need.